# ¿Cómo reducir la cantidad de atributos de los elementos de un array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array en Javascript con los siguientes objetos

```
let listado = [ 
    { a: 1, b: 3, c: 3, d: 4 }, 
    { a: 2, b: 13, c: 6, d: 9 },  
    { a: 53, b: 12, c: 98, d: 27 } 
];
```

Lo que quiero es a cada elemento del array reducirle la cantidad de atributos a solo un numero especifico, por decir algo que para el listado del ejemplo solo queden los atributos `a` y `c`:

```
listado = [ 
    { a: 1, c: 3 }, 
    { a: 2, c: 6 },  
    { a: 53, c: 98 } 
];
```

¿Existe alguna función de javascript que me haga esto o hay que ir recorriendo elemento por elemento en el array e ir eliminando los atributos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Lo que quiero es a cada elemento del array reducirle la cantidad de atributos a solo un numero especifico, por decir algo que para el listado del ejemplo solo queden los atributos a y c

"Reducir" la cantidad de atributos seria algo permanente que afectaria al arreglo original, este tipo de efectos colaterales pueden ser nocivos para otro componente. Si queres usar el enfoque de programacion funcional, la opcion es usar la funcion [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Lo que debes hacer es retornar un nuevo objeto que tenga "la forma" que quieres.

```js
let listado = [ 
    { a: 1, b: 3, c: 3, d: 4 }, 
    { a: 2, b: 13, c: 6, d: 9 },  
    { a: 53, b: 12, c: 98, d: 27 } 
];
  
var resultado = listado.map(function(item){
  return { a: item.a, c: item.c };
});

console.log(
  resultado
);
```

Entonces, lo que estas haciendo es crear un nuevo arreglo con nuevos objetos, dejando el arreglo original intacto, lo cual es muy util si a continuancion debes crear otro arreglo pero con una forma diferente.

Si esto fuese nodejs (en lugar de un browser) podrias hacerlo mas simple con arrow functions.

```
listado.map(item => ({a: item.a, c: item.c}));
```

Incluso usando *[object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)* puedes simplificarlo

```
listado.map(({a,c}) => ({a,c}));
```

Nota: se menciona que esto funciona en browsers y es correcto pero no en todos, estas caracteristicas son propias de ECMAScript 2015 y hay muchos navegadores no soportan estas caracteristicas, pero siguen en el mercado. Dependiendo del navegador minimo al que apunta tu desarrollo, podrias considerar utilizarlo o no.

Comment: incluso puede ser mas simple, si usaas `console.log(listado.map(({a, c}) => {return {a, c}; }));
`

Comment: ademas la ultima linea no funciona, tienes que poner `{a: item.a, b:item.b}`

Comment: .map tambien es usado en el browser, no necesitas nodeJs para eso

Comment: Normalmente seria nocivo pero para el caso que necesito no, el tema es que quiero hacer exactamente eso, para este caso la API me devuelve ciertos atributos innecesarios para la tarea dentro de cada elemento y por un tema de reutilizar un componente preexistente que lee todos los elementos quiero evitar esa tarea.

Comment: @RicardoD.Quiroga si quieres eliminar un atributo de un objeto la unica opcion es usar `delete objeto.propiedad;` o (`delete objeto['propiedad']`).. puedes hacerlo usando un `forEach` por ejemplo. Pero eso afectaria al otro componenten preexistente (en caso de q ambos esten accediendo a la misma instancia del arreglo).

Answer (score 1):

Admito que no conozco una funcion nativa que lo haga pero puedes utilizar esta funcion que solo deja las propiedades que le especifiques en el segundo parametro:

```js
function compactar(datos, propiedades)
{
   var result = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < datos.length;i++)
   {
      var obj ={};
      for(var b = 0; b < propiedades.length; b++)
      {
          obj[propiedades[b]]= datos[i][propiedades[b]];
      }
      
      result.push(obj);
   }
   
   return result;
};

var listado = [ 
    { a: 1, b: 3, c: 3, d: 4 }, 
    { a: 2, b: 13, c: 6, d: 9 },  
    { a: 53, b: 12, c: 98, d: 27 } 
];


console.log(compactar(listado,['a', 'c']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe una función nativa que hace el trabajo por ti. Se llama [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete)

Aquí un ejemplo con tus objetos que colocas:

```js
let listado = [ 
    { a: 1, b: 3, c: 3, d: 4 }, 
    { a: 2, b: 13, c: 6, d: 9 },  
    { a: 53, b: 12, c: 98, d: 27 } 
];

listado.map(function(lista) {
  return delete lista.b
})

console.log(listado)
```

Y bueno, lo que hago es usar .[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) para recorrer el array contenedor de objetos y por cada iteración aplico delete a la propiedad deseada.

Comment: .map devuelve un array con los elemenos que devuelve la función que le pasas, así que en este caso crearías un nuevo array pero también modificarías los elementos del original. Podrías simplemente hacer un forEach para modificar los elementos

Comment: @PabloLozano tienes toda la razón, preferible un foreach

Comment: creo que es preferible un map, pues es la solucion immutable, y con el foreach lo que estarias haciendo es simular el .map

Comment: @DanielPérez No es inmutable: delete borra realmente el atributo del item original, no de una copia.

Comment: Si, a eso es lo que me refiero, quizas no m explique bien :(, map es la solucion immutable, por eso es preferible, el foreach no lo es